# flutter can not use reordableListView in a screen that contain two listview

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

this is my code that i have a row that contain two stack that every one have a list view left widget has a stack that contain a reordablelistView but when drag a element of it get this error

```
Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      width: width,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          RightWidget(),// a listview
          Container(
            width: 1.5,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          LeftWidget()
        ],
      ),
    ),)
```

and my reordablelistview is

```
class _RightWidgetState extends State<RightWidget> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print('right widget called');
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[


    Container(
      color: Color(0xFF1B1D22),
      width: (1 / 4) * width + 10,
      child://new reordable list added



       ReorderableListView(

                  children:
                List.generate(Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>(context).classes[Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>                      (context).numberclass].moves.length, (index) {
                  return _itemBuilder(context,index);
                }), onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {

                Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>(context).changeMoveIndex(newIndex, oldIndex);

                })
```

and i get this errors

```
I/flutter (25693): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.0 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter (25693): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.0 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter (25693): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 11 pixels on the right.
I/flutter (25693): Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
```

my widget that use it in list is

```
Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int count) {
 print('video thumbnail build in listview');
 return GestureDetector(
  key: UniqueKey(),//new
   onTap: () {
    // Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>(context).setOptionView(context);//set options for view
    //ToDo:if name dont update must refresh moves of class lenght
    Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>(context,listen: false).setMoveIndex(count);
    Provider.of<CheckOneRunVideo>(context,listen: false).setIndex(count);

    if (Provider.of<ButtonAddStateBloc>(context).editingState)
      Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>(context)
          .classes[Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>(context).numberclass]
          .moves[count]
          .isselectedfor =
      !Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>(context)
          .classes[Provider.of<ClassroomBlac>(context).numberclass]
          .moves[count]
          .isselectedfor;
  },
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
    child: VideoThumbnailItem(count),
  ));
 }
```

please help me if i use contoroller if yes how if i generate list items correctly ?
what is incorrect?

when i comment leftWidget() that contain a listview my code work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common fix for this kind of problem is to assign a controller to your `Scrollable`.
Unfortunately `ReorderableListView` doesn't include a public property for this.

The best solution I know is to wrap your `ReorderableListView` (and only this) in a `PrimaryScrollController` and give it a ScrollController. It works because `ReorderableListView` assigns the `PrimaryScrollController` of its `context` to its private `_scrollController`.

```
return PrimaryScrollController(
  controller: myScrollController,
  child: ReorderableListView(...),
);
```

Another less elegant option is to rewrite the ReorderableListView widget and expose the scrollController property in the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this existed when you encountered this problem, but the [ReorderableListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html) now has a scrollController property.

So declare your scrollController like this:

```
final ScrollController reorderScrollController = ScrollController();
```

And then assign that unique scrollController to your ReorderableListView:

```
ReorderableListView(
   scrollController: reorderScrollController,
   ...
)
```